# Can you automate a release that changes the type of a field that is referenced by a class?

Tags: deployment, destructivechanges.xml

**The problem**

In production we have a field that is referenced by a class.

We want to change that field from a 'text' field to a 'formula' field.

In order to change the field from one type to another our normal practice would be to include it in a pre-deployment destructive change and allow the deployment to re-instate it in the new format.

In this particular circumstance this fails as Salesforce states the field is currently in use.

It doesn't appear that we can remove the class in an automated manner and then let the ant deployment re-instate the field in the correct format.

Salesforce workaround appears to be to use an IDE and point and click.

- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006188

Ideally everything in a deployment should be as automated as possible so that we can "one-click-deploy".

Does anyone have any ideas of how we can implement this deployment in an automated manner?

**Some other background**

We store all our Salesforce configuration in Bitbucket and we create and deploy artifacts using Bamboo.

We do not use change sets.

The developers and technical staff in the organisation come from a non-Salesforce background and are used to these problems being solvable.

Comment: We have come up with 1 solution that I'm not 100% happy with, but at least it works.  We made a small release package blacking out the references in the classes and then making the destructive change.  We then run the normal release package which adds the field back in the correct format.  This works only because we're moving from to a formula field and so data loss isn't an issue.  I suspect we may use variations on this idea in the future though for more complex releases.

Answer (score 0):

Switch and deprecate. Create a new (formula) field and edit your class to reflect this new field. Deploy and migrate data if required. Then delete the old field. That should work.

Comment: I accept that this appears to be the standard line.  But how about if that field is referenced by 3 other systems - I then need to release all those systems too.  All because I wanted to change the way in which the value was populated.

Comment: Well my assumption was that you wanted an interuption free transfer. If you're fine with some small loss of service, then first delete the field and all references (make sure you delete-delete from the recycle bin) then create the field with the same api name but now as a formula field. I don't think salesforce has the ability to switch over in one turn unfortunately.